# Linting not working when using babel-eslint on Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, lint, babeljs

I am trying to get babel-eslint to work on Sublime 3. I have installed:

- eslint and babel-eslint globally on npm
- SublimeLinter package on Sublime
- SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint package on Sublime

Also, I have added:
 `"syntax_map": { ... "JavaScript (Babel)": "javascript" }` to my SublimeLinter.sublime-settings file.

When I run the linter with `"parser": "espree"` on my .eslintrc file it works fine. But when I change the parser to babel-eslint it stops working.

I tried to follow the tutorial here: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/lint-like-it-s-2015-6987d44c5b48 and I seem to be doing everything correctly.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Except what was in mentioned tutorial, what helped me was:

- upgrade global / local eslint to latest version
- install babel-eslint locally
- if you are using any eslint plugins, it appears they must be also installed locally (eslint-plugin-react in my case)
- as Dalgard mentioned you can also enable debug mode in Sublime eslint to find out what else can be wrong, i.e. incompatible versions or corrupted config.

I hope some of this will help.

Comment: I did all three steps and it's working perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: I was having problems with this too. I would never imagine that it was necessary to install eslint-plugin-react locally =/

Tks a lot!

Comment: This is not enough to make it work for me – can you confirm that your setup also work with the newest versions? eslint@2.3.0, babel-eslint@5.0.0

Comment: I just figured out enabling debug mode (!) and see a message that the versions are not compatible. I'll simply make sure compatible versions are installed.

Comment: Run `eslint --init` in proj dir